# Creating an RxJava Subject that doesn't terminate on complete or error

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to create an RxJava 2 `Subject` that can subscribe to an `Observable`, but doesn't terminate when the subscribed `Observable` terminates either due to error or completion.

Essentially, this will act as an event bus that can subscribe to other `Observable`s.

What's the right way to do this, to avoid propagating the termination and also avoiding leaks?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/

Answer (score 0):

Your best option I think it´s use the operator "relay" which wont unsubscribe once all items has been emitted in the pipeline

```
   /**
     * Relay is just an observable which subscribe an observer, but it wont unsubscribe once emit the items. So the pipeline keep open
     * It should return 1,2,3,4,5 for first observer and just 3, 4, 5 fot the second observer since default relay emit last emitted item,
     * and all the next items passed to the pipeline.
     */
    @Test
    public void testRelay() throws InterruptedException {
        BehaviorRelay<String> relay = BehaviorRelay.create("default");
        relay.subscribe(result -> System.out.println("Observer1:" + result));
        relay.call("1");
        relay.call("2");
        relay.call("3");
        relay.subscribe(result -> System.out.println("Observer2:" + result));
        relay.call("4");
        relay.call("5");
    }
```

You can see more examples of relay here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/relay/Relay.java

Answer (score 0):

In RxJava3 I could with this with Observable.flatMap():

```java
    @Test
    void testReplacingObservable() {
        Subject<Observable<Integer>> observableStream = UnicastSubject.create();
        Observable<Integer> integerStream = observableStream.flatMap(observable -> observable);
        TestObserver<Integer> observer = integerStream.test();

        // now can keep adding new observables to the source observable stream
        observableStream.onNext(Observable.just(0, 1, 2, 3, 4));
        observableStream.onNext(Observable.just(5, 6));
        observableStream.onNext(Observable.just(7, 8, 9));

        observer.assertValueCount(10);
        observer.assertValueAt(0, 0);
        observer.assertValueAt(5, 5);
        observer.assertValueAt(7, 7);
    }
```